# What the difference between this Post webrequest and similar request in Postman?

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest, postman

I want to make Post request to "https://sslecal2.forexprostools.com/ajax.php". So there is my code:

```
        string URI = "https://sslecal2.forexprostools.com/ajax.php";
        string requestBody = String.Format("{{\"dateFrom\": \"{0}\", \"dateTo\": \"{1}\", \"timeZone\": {2}, \"action\": \"{3}\"}}",
                                           "2018-12-24", "2018-12-24", 18, "filter"); //json format

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URI);  //make request         
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.UserAgent = "";
        request.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            writer.Write(requestBody); //write your request payload
        }

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        string jsonData = String.Empty;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            jsonData = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        response.Close();
```

I made something not correct in "requestBody" in string " string requestBody = String.Format("{{\"dateFrom\"..." because I get 200 and empty html answer.

And I attach the screens of the same request in postman with html code in answer. This request in postman processes well.

What the difference between this Post webrequest and request in Postman?
[image: headers]

[image: body with answer]

Comment: Try setting the user agent.

Comment: Your postman version is using `x-www-form-urlencoded` which is not JSON.  (to use JSON, you'd use "raw" for the body, and make your `Content-Type` `application/json`.)  I'd start with changing postman to use JSON to see if that works.  (so you have an apples to apples comparison) If not, you're stuck with using `x-www-form-urlencoded`.  You should be able to google to see how to do that in C#.

Comment: @Neijwiert tried `request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko";` - restul is same

Comment: @KirkWoll thanks, it's interesting suggestion, because when I switched postman to raw and `{"dateFrom": "2018-12-24","dateTo": "2018-12-24","timeZone": 18,"action":"filter"}` I got the same result: 200 and empty html in answer.

Comment: @mr_blond yup, then you're stuck with the urlencoded approach Reniuz outlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With postman you posting different format data. To get same thing in code you need to change request body format and set content type of request:

```
string URI = "https://sslecal2.forexprostools.com/ajax.php";
string requestBody = String.Format("dateFrom={0}&dateTo={1}&timeZone={2}&action={3}",
"2018-12-24", "2018-12-24", 18, "filter"); //<-- Change this

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URI); 
request.Method = "POST";
request.UserAgent = "";
request.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; //<-- Add this
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    writer.Write(requestBody); 
}

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
string jsonData = String.Empty;

using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    jsonData = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
response.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

In PostMan, if you click the "Code" in the top right, under the send button, you can choose C# (RestSharp).. If you're not using RestSharp, there's a small amount of work to do to convert it to something else, but the basics are all there.

Here's the autogen output for your case (RestSharp):

```
var client = new RestClient("https://sslecal2.forexprostools.com/ajax.php");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "bfd1a3b3-983f-4160-a091-6f0962413e58");
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("undefined", "dateFrom=2018-01-24&dateTo=2018-01-24&timeZone=18&action=filter", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Converting it to HttpWebRequest requires:

- AddHeader -> Headers.Add
- Specify method
- Body data is set differently - take PostMan's string and write it to the request stream

Or install RestSharp free from NuGet